# Indicating entity-user relationship in REST APIs

Tags: rest, twitter, api-design

Assume you are designing Twitter REST API. There are entities called `tweet`s. Users are able to `retweet` and `favorite` those tweets. If you request a `tweet` or an aggretation of tweets with an user authentication parameters, how would you indicate that authenticated user has already `retweeted` and `favorited` those tweets without need to a second API request?

Currently, [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-entities) does not have such fields on `tweet` entities but somehow its official clients and some 3rd party clients are able to infer whether that tweet is already favorited or retweeted by authenticated user.

By convention, REST responses contain metadata of entities, not the user-entity relationships if I'm not wrong. How does that happen, if you would implement Twitter API, where would you put such fields or would you initiate a second request each of the tweets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweet Entities are specifically about the text of each status. The full [status object](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/show/%3aid) does include attributes like `"favorited": false` and `"retweeted": false`. I believe this has caused Twitter issues with caching however so you might consider a different format.

```
{
  "data": {
    "id":"123",
    "text":"blah blah"
  },
  "relationship": {
    "favorited": true,
    "retweeted": false
  },
  "links": { ... }
}
```

This way `data` can be cached globally and `relationship` can be the users specific `relationship` to the `data`.

Comment: That's a cool idea, I haven't noticed those fields on full status object, because it's damn complicated :) Thanks for the idea but don't you also believe that data should be directly in the root of json response object by convention?

Comment: I think it depends somewhat on type of data and the functionality of the site. For example a social site could include a `notifications` object next to `data` that could include new followers, messages, etc and that would get rid of the need for frequently requesting a separate notifications method.